# Unable to access nodes/tags in JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Trying to learn Python finally. Having read all the other questions on the topic I have deducted I am an idiot.

I'm making a Python request to an open API like below

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users'
payload = [{"name": "tbone"}]
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

This all goes well and I can print the response

```
print r.text
```

However, it's when I want to access certain tags/nodes in the response that I run into a wall. The output is

```
[{"country":"se","medals":[34,54,13,5,46,28,16,6],"zones":[323,7577,14606],"pointsPerHour":21,"points":21809,"blocktime":17,"taken":2290,"name":"tbone","totalPoints":347388,"rank":30,"id":95195,"place":1931,"uniqueZonesTaken":269,"region":{"name":"Stockholm","id":141}}]
```

And I've tried to

```
rj = r.json()
print rj['name']
```

But that only gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "post.py", line 16, in <module>
print rj['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I cannot get my head around how to access any individual tags/nodes in the JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you got : `[{"country":"se",..."region":{"name":"Stockholm","id":141}}]`
is a list of JSON objects (notice the `[]` surrounding the dictionary).

So, to get your object, you have to do :

```
rj = r.json()
print rj[0]['name']    # the [0] to indicate you take the first element of your list
```